# Flutter detect any user interaction with the app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, timer

I'm creating an app that needs to **locally** log out the user after x seconds of inactivity. I'm able to catch most of the users action by using the `Listener` widget. However I it does not detect when a user is typing text, taping a button inside a dialog or selecting a dropdown value.
**How do I detect any user interaction with the app?**

Comment: why you even want to code using this approach? This should be handled with backend. On the frontend, you should check for jwt_access_token. if that is invalid you should send a jwt_refresh_token in the header, so the backend api will send you new jwt_access_token, you keep it the memory. if the user had not made any api call the jwt_access_token will expire and you should logout them immediately.

Comment: This is a time punching terminal app. A user will log in by scanning his card via nfc. After some time if no actionts were taken the user should be logged out.

Comment: Can you explain, in a little more detail? That will help me or even other to understand the problem statement better and help you.

Comment: The app is used to track workers time and fill out small forms. For a user to be able to 'log in' they need to scan an nfc card, then they are show a screen with buttons 'start shift' and 'end shift'. When they press either of those buttons they can manually 'log out' to let other workers 'log in' or fill out a form. If the app has not received any interaction for a set period of time the currently 'logged in' user should be logged out.

Comment: To be even clearer the log in and log out of a user does not require internet connection. We have a special admin user that logs into the terminal and gets the data of all of the users that are authorized to use the terminal. After admin log in regular users may use the terminal to log in / out and proceed to use the app